# incompatible pointer types char** and char* error

Tags: c, pointers

```
void decimal2binary(char *decimal, char *binary) {   
    //method information goes here    
}
```

This is the main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char *data[100];
if (argc != 4) {
    printf("invalid number of arguments\n");
    return 1;
}
if (strcmp(argv[1] , "-d")) {

    if (strcmp(argv[3] , "-b")) {
        decimal2binary(temp, data);
    }
    }
}
```

Now I get this error

```
     warning: passing argument 2 of ‘decimal2binary’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

     note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

So it says they are incompatible types but I have to use argv to get the data (that how I was asked) is there any other way?

Comment: Accept the answer from Json, if it worked for you.   ;)
Json has given correct explaination

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the declaration of `data` to simply:

```
char data[100];
```

You don't need an array of pointers to type `char`, which is what you've declared as your code stands right now.  You simply want a byte array.  I believe your confusion stems from the fact that while arrays are not pointers, they do decay into pointers to the first element of the array when passed as a function argument.  So by simply saying `decimal2binary(temp, data);`, you are passing a pointer to the first element of `data`, and in this case you need that to be a pointer to a `char`, not a `char*`.